# Merging two Sharepoint Directories

Tags: windows-explorer, filesystems, file-transfer, file-management, onedrive

I'm wondering if anyone has any experience in merging file systems. I have two SharePoint directories (with countless subdirectories...), one ~1.5TB and one ~0.5TB, that need to be merged together. I basically want to create one directory with no duplicate or missing contents.

I was able to sync these with OneDrive to a windows 2019 VM. I attached a 4TB drive and have *both* file systems downloaded to the VM. I disabled Files On-Demand, so every file is available locally.

I am aware of Robocopy and RichCopy, but the latter was last updated almost a decade ago. Is there a new version or anything better? Has anyone else worked with such large file systems before; any tips?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!
Thank you,

Comment: Robocopy can do everything apart from the "no duplicate contents" part. If the exact same file existed in different locations in the folder structure, each instance would be included.